# How does lex match tokens

Tags: tokenize, lex, lexer

I am learning lex. I made a simple lex file containing one rule:

```
%%
“Hello”      puts(“response\n”);
%%
```

After running `lex file.l`, I’d like to inspect the outputted file `file.yy.c`. I presume that the lexer stores the tokens somehow, and matches it (probably with a switch statement) with the input. Looking at the file, I am able to see the output (`puts(“response\n”);`, but I cannot find the tokens themselves. I can see many tables (matrices?) in the outputted file, but I cannot figure out how they are translated into the tokens.
Any help explaining how tokens are matched by the lexer is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lex` builds a state machine (a [DFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton)) that consumes one character at a time until each reaches a state that can't match any longer token, and then runs the code corresponding to the longest token it found.

In your example, it will build a very simple DFA with about 7 states -- from an initial state that will match 'H' that goes to second state matching 'e' etc.  If it gets to the 6th state (after matching the 'o') it will print the message, but any of the states on any other character will go to a state that does the default "single character echo" action.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain how the DFA is represented in the lex output file?

Comment: @Maslin: As a compressed table whose keys are (effectively) (state, char) pairs and whose values are the new state. The compression techniques (of which there are several possibilities selectable with command-line flags) make analysing the table less than straight-forward.

Comment: In other words, you won't find the tokens in the lexical analyser. Anyway, in the general case, tokens are not literal strings but rather regular expressions. And since the regular expressions are compiled into a DFA, they're not kept in the generated code, not even for debugging purposes.